# What are these flying things called in English?

Tags: word-request, vocabulary, image-identification

I saw something flying today. What should I call it in English?

[image: something in the air]

Comment: They are [(hot) air balloons](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hot_air_balloon).

Comment: It would be more natural sounding to phrase your question "What are these called in English?", though I don't know if using "how" is technically incorrect.  To use "how" , I would say "How are these described in English?".

Answer (score 21, accepted):

bytebuster has the provided the correct term, although I would parenthesize it like this: *(hot air) balloon*. That is, these objects can simply be called *balloons*, or *hot-air balloons* if you want to be more specific.

Also, it may be worth noting that [many dictionaries](http://onelook.com/?w=hot+air+balloon&ls=a) hyphenate the descriptive *hot-air*, although that hyphen is regularly omitted in the [literature](http://www.google.com/search?q=hot+air+balloon&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1).

Hot air balloons belong to the family of flying machines called *[aerostats](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aerostat)*, or lighter-than-air flying aircraft. However, it should be noted that I've added that hypernym simply for reference purposes; the word *aerostat* is a more technical term that's seldom heard in day-to-day speech. In conversation, I'd expect to hear something more like:

> Blimps and hot-air balloons are *lighter-than-air* aircraft.

Comment: I'm going to have to start using aerostat now.