# What is the type of movement of hot-air balloons called in English?

Tags: word-request

The question about [hot-air balloons](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/2500/232)* got me thinking: What do you call their type of movement in English? In German it is **not** *"fliegen"* (flying) but *"fahren"* (shipping, possibly driving). What is it in English?

*: Balloons which are unpowered, without engines or propellers; they can only move up and down due to buoyancy changes (lifted by helium/hydrogen/hot air) and are otherwise at the mercy of the wind.

Comment: Just to clarify, you're talking about unpowered balloons that can only move up and down due to buoyancy changes, and are otherwise at the mercy of the wind? Blimps (non-rigid airships) and dirigibles/rigid airships have engines and propellers that give them limited horizontal movement and control, but are usually lifted by helium (or, until the _Hindenburg_, hydrogen).

Comment: @PhilPerry: Yes, you are right, I included it in the question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are a number of words you can choose here.

> The balloons **floated** over the valley.
>
> The balloons gently **drifted** over the trees.
>
> As they released them, the balloons **flew** into the sky.

In the active sense, i.e. when the balloon is being directed, avoid the word *drive*, and prefer instead either the word *pilot*, *fly* or *navigate*:

> The aviator took the controls and **piloted** the balloon through the storm.
>
> The aviator took the controls and **flew** the balloon through the storm.
>
> The aviator took the controls and **navigated** the balloon through the storm.

Comment: Hot air balloons are basically at the mercy of the prevailing wind, so "drifted" is probably the word of choice here.  Upward motion is controlled by heating the air in the balloon, and down, either by not heating the air and hoping it cools off enough to sink to a lower level, or releasing air by opening a hatch in the top of the balloon -- which can usually be done exactly once, for landing.  Different air "layers" can have air currents moving in different directions, which gives a skilled pilot limited ability to control the sideways direction by moving up or down into a different current.

Comment: I like this answer, and I would personally choose "float" with "drift" as my second choice.  I also like the sound of "The hot air balloon wafted through the air", but it's not something people say very often.

Comment: Although "waft" is usable, I would tend to use it more in the sense of something _diffusing_ **through** the air (e.g., an odor), as opposed to a physical object [balloon] moving **with** the air.

Answer (score 7):

*Float*.

Hot-air baloons *float* in air exactly the way bricks don't.

Comment: I like the Douglas Adams reference :)

Comment: What about very small bricks?